# How do you say bot in chinese?

Tags: technology

The bot I am referring to is a software program that does automated tasks.

I was thinking of if "器" is the right character for it.

I confirmed it with wordreference but does not appear to have a translation for it.

Is there actually a better translation than the one I have mentioned?

Comment: `器` is too general for it. You could say `机器人程序`.

Comment: 机器人程序 is more for a physical robot I believe.
I am referring to like software implemented on software kind of thing.

Comment: `机器人` is physical robot. `程序` is software, so `机器人程序` refer to  software basically. http://dict.youdao.com/w/bot/#keyfrom=dict2.top

Comment: More like software for a physical robot from what I know.

Comment: All software programs do automatic tasks. The thing which you are thinking probably can be translated to `机器人程序` but it's likely you could use a more specific word.

Answer (score 1):

The "bot" as a software program could be translated just like the physical robots as "機器人" (literal meaning is "machine"+"person") in the Mandarin Chinese; or it would also be called more specifically as "機器人程序" or "機器人程式" ("robot"+"program").

But, in the spoken Chinese, people may just borrow the original English word "bot" instead of using any localized translations mentioned above.

Some educational or academic sources would suggest some complex terms but they are rarely being used in the actual conversations or texts.